# Handler Issues Applying cdll in Python

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

I'm trying to porting some C dll(FANUC FOCAS Library - for CNC) code via Python using ctypes, so I wrote porting code. (as belows), but get a very strange result when loading the DLL and calling the function. In my case, I don't understand using handler in python.

I would like to apply the following c code in python.

**Declaration(for c)**

```
#include "fwlib64.h"
FWLIBAPI short WINAPI cnc_allclibhndl3(const char *ipaddr,unsigned short port,
long timeout, unsigned short *FlibHndl);
```

**Example Code(in focas library manual for c)**

```
#include "fwlib64.h"
void example( void )
{
unsigned short h;               
short ret;                           
ODBST buf;                        
ret = cnc_allclibhndl3( "192.168.0.100", 8193, 1, &h ) ; 
//
if ( !ret ) {
        cnc_statinfo( h, &buf ) ;    
        cnc_freelibhndl( h ) ;       
} else {
        printf( "ERROR!(%d)\n", ret ) ;   
}
}
```

**Testfocas.py**

```
from ctypes import *
mylib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./Fwlib64.dll')
class ODBSYS(Structure):
    pass
_fields_ =[
    ("dummy", c_ushort),
    ("max_axis", c_char*2),
    ("cnc_type", c_char*2),
    ("mt_type",c_char*2),
    ("series",c_char*4),
    ("version",c_char*4),
    ("axes",c_char*2),]

h=c_ushort()
pt=pointer(h)
ret=c_short()
buf=ODBSYS()

ret=mylib.cnc_allclibhndl3('192.168.0.100',8193,1,pt)
mylib.cnc_statinfo(h,buf)
mylib.cnc_freelibhndl(h)
```

I want the function to return 0 or -16 but, in my case the function return is

> cnc_allclibhndl3 = 65520 (i guess open port)
>
> cnc_statinfo = -8
>
> cnc_freelibhndl -8

**Return Status of Data Window Functions**

```
EW_OK(0)  Normal termination  
EW_SOCKET(-16)  Socket communication error Check the power supply of CNC, Ethernet I/F board, Ethernet connection cable. 
EW_HANDLE(-8)  Allocation of handle number is failed.
```

I do not know what I was wrong with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CDLL` is for `__cdecl` calling convention.  `cdll` is not recommended for use because it is a shared instance across modules.

`WINAPI` is defined as `__stdcall`, so use `WinDLL`:

```
mylib = WinDLL.LoadLibrary('./Fwlib64.dll')
```

Next, define `argtypes` and `restype` for your argument and result types for your function:

```
mylib.cnc_allclibhndl3.argtypes = c_char_p,c_ushort,c_long,POINTER(c_ushort)
mylib.cnc_allclibhndl3.restype = c_short
```

Finally, pass the output parameter by reference.  It is more efficient than creating a `pointer`:

```
h = c_ushort()
ret = mylib.cnc_allclibhndl3('192.168.0.100',8193,1,byref(h))
```

Prototypes for `cnc_statinfo` and `cnc_freelibhndl` were not provided.  Define  `argtypes` and `restype` for them as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

After modifying the above source code, the following error occurs.

ret=mylib.cnc_allclibhndl3('192.168.0.100',8193,1,byref(h))
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type

Comment: You're likely on Python 3. Pass a byte string as the first parameter. `b'192.168.0.100'`. Unicode strings correspond to `c_wchar_t`.

Comment: You are right. My development environment is 'Python3'. Thank you for your help!